# Create variable outside function to use inside function with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, scope

I am trying to create a global variable to use inside other functions. I am creating conditional statements so that I can use those variables inside multiple functions without having to write redundant code.

```
let x = "";
if (filters.group == "day") {
  x = new Date(elem.date);
} else if (filters.grou == "month") {
  x = new Date(elem.year, elem.month)
}
```

Functions to use in:

```js
$.getJSON(jsonOne, result => {
  result.forEach(elem => {
    series1.data.push({
      x: +xaxis,
      y: elem.starts
    });

    series2.data.push({
      x: +xaxis
      y: elem.completes
    });
  });
});

$.getJSON(jsonTwo, result => {
  result.forEach(elem => {
    series3.data.push({
      x: +xaxis,
      y: elem.rev
    });

    series4.data.push({
      x: +xaxis,
      y: elem.val
    });
  });
}),
```

Error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: elem is not defined

Error at `x = new Date(elem.date);`

I understand why I am getting the error but I don't know how to fix it. Please help!

Comment: How does the first code sample relate to the second? It appears `elem` is not in scope

Comment: Where is `x = new Date(elem.date);` located in the code relative to the $.getJSON call? The  easiest solution is probably to just turn the date creation thing into a function you can call from within getJSON. Keep in mind you'll also need access to the filters.

Comment: I know its not in scope but is there a way to use a variable outside of scope considering I am using it in so many functions?

Comment: @Shilly How do I do that?

Comment: Yes, declare it globally, but that's generally bad practice and should be avoided. It's a better idea to pass the data to functions where required

Comment: You can, hence we ask where it is located in the code, so we know which variables have to be available where. But this is just less-than-optimal structure.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Sorry I am very confused about how to go about how to go about this now.

Comment: @Shilly Sorry, i am still confused

Comment: I dont get this - what are you trying to do? By splitting your code up in these two section s I have no idea _where_ what is located. If your `let x` definition is global, then where does `elem` come from? If you only want to process `x` once you have `elem`, you will need to do the operation in the function or call another wrapped function to get the correct `Date` object. Please make your code functional and clear so we know what is going on.

Comment: Just pass your `elem` to desired scope in argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking something like this:

You create a function that returns a date object when you give it the element and the filters as parameters.

The issue here is that as you see, you also need the `filters`. And also the `series1`. And also the `xaxis`. Hence a solution using global variables like this is not recommended. But explaining better JS structure is a whole different question and answer you can find somewhere here by searching.

```js
/* getJSON mockup for testing */
const getJSON = function( url, callback ) {
  callback([
    {
      date: '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
      year: 2019,
      month: 0,
      starts: 24
    },
    {
      date: '2019-03-13T14:51:02.021Z',
      year: 2019,
      month: 2,
      starts: 29
    }
  ]);
};

const cast_date = function( elem, filters ) {
  if ( filters.group === 'day' ) return new Date(elem.date);
  else if ( filters.group === 'month' ) return new Date(elem.year, elem.month);
  else throw new Error( `cannot create date for element ${ elem }, no valid filter group: ${ filters.group }` );

};

const filters = {
  group: 'day'
};

const series1 = {
  data: []
};

const xaxis = '20';

getJSON( 'jsonOne', result => {
  result.forEach(elem => {
  
    const date = cast_date( elem, filters );
    
    console.log( `created date: ${ date }` );
  
    series1.data.push({
      x: +xaxis,
      y: elem.starts
    });

  });
  console.log( series1 );
});
```